# Redis client using Ruby

Tags: ruby, redis

I am trying to get user input for **AGE** attribute and comparing it with my key value pair and trying to return those records which match the user input value.

Code:

```
require "redis"
require "csv"
require "json"

begin
  redis = Redis.new(:url => "redis://h:petr08jsjnofis211gmbq8fdd8@ec2-54-83-9-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com:11959")
  puts "Connected"

  health = CSV.read('6339_Dataset_1.csv')

  health.each do |data_row|
    redis.hmset(data_row[21],"AGE",data_row[0],"SEX",data_row[1],"RACE",data_row[2],"DAY_OF_ADMISSION",data_row[3],"DISCHARGE_STATUS",data_row[4],"STAY_INDICATOR",data_row[5],"ID",data_row[21])
  end

  value = redis.keys('*')
  puts "QUERY 2"
  puts "Enter the AGE:"
  age = gets

  value.each do |data|
    #puts id
    val = redis.hgetall(data)
    val.each do |key, value|
        if key == "AGE" && value == age
            puts redis.hgetall(data)
        else
            puts "NO"
        end
    end     
  end
end
```

Problem:
 I am able to get the output if I hard coded **AGE** but if I get the user input it just goes to the else section.

Comment: This is where just a tiny bit of debug printing would've been useful. `age` you get from `gets` contains a newline. You can get rid of it by using `gets.chomp` for example

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.to_i` in the line you check for *AGE* key, like:

```
if key == "AGE" && value.to_i == age.to_i
```

Also, the second `value` variable shadows outer `value` variable.
Better to change `value = redis.keys('*')` to something like,

```
 keys = redis.keys('*')
```

Comment: Shadowing, yes, but it doesn't do any harm here.

Comment: I changed my answer as per your feedback, prioritising the facts.